# How can I move different information from the same person (on different transactions) on different row into one row?

Tags: python, database, pandas

I have a dataframe in Pandas like this:

```
Id      Name    LogIn
1       Kate    01/10/16
2       Nancy   02/21/17
3       Kate    03/12/17
4       Kate    04/17/17
5       Nancy   05/10/17
```

These are "logging in" information of different customer. I want to have each customer in one row only and list of his/her "log in" dates. Something like:

```
Name    LogIn1     LogIn2    LogIn3
Kate    01/10/16   03/12/17  04/17/17
Nancy   02/21/17   05/19/17  Nan
```

How can I do it in Pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not mind for me to change the log1 to log0

```
df.groupby('Name').LogIn.apply(list).apply(pd.Series).add_prefix('LogIn')
Out[332]: 
         LogIn0    LogIn1    LogIn2
Name                               
Kate   01/10/16  03/12/17  04/17/17
Nancy  02/21/17  05/10/17       NaN
```

If you need that exactly same .

```
df=df.groupby('Name').LogIn.apply(list).apply(pd.Series)
df.columns+=1
df.add_prefix('LogIn').rename_axis(None)
Out[338]: 
         LogIn1    LogIn2    LogIn3
Kate   01/10/16  03/12/17  04/17/17
Nancy  02/21/17  05/10/17       NaN
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, there is just one more piece to the problem that I couldn't figure it out. What if for each LogIn event, I have a corresponding 'duration'? How can I make Login1, Duration1, LogIn2, Duration2 and so on?

Comment: @N.Tamimi do it separately and pd.concate them

Comment: Yes, you are right. Hard to do it at the same time. Thanks again.